# Application.CommandBars("vbaPopup").ShowPopup ··· how can I add `Submenu` (Ron de Bruin)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Microsoft Office 365 2019.

First of all i want to tell how code works:

1. Insert Note.
2. Click on Cell who has inserted Note.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
   Then you will see "PopUp-Menu".
   [image]

---

I have VBA code (to work put in ThisWorkbook):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^{n}", CodeName & ".ContextMenu"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "^{n}"
End Sub

Private Sub ContextMenu()
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next 'Can be and without inadequate to, but then with brute force(cycle) CommandBars.
    Dim cb As CommandBar
    Set cb = Application.CommandBars("vbaPopup")
    If cb Is Nothing Then CreateContextMenu

    Application.CommandBars("vbaPopup").ShowPopup
End Sub

Private Sub CreateContextMenu()
    Dim a1_icon, a1_file, a2, a3, i&, m$, p$, f$: m = CodeName & ".": p = Path & "\Image\"
    a1_icon = Array(76, 72, 178, 53)
    a1_file = Array("NoteZoom_200x110.jpg", "NoteZoom_600x400.jpg", "Full Screen.jpg", "NoteZoom_InputBox.jpg", "Copy Text.jpg")
    a2 = Array("NoteZoom 200x110", "NoteZoom 600x400", "Note <Full Screen>", "NoteZoom InputBox", "Скопировать текст примечания")
    a3 = Array("NoteZoom1", "NoteZoom2", "NoteZoom3", "NoteZoom_InputBox", "NoteTextToClipboard")

    With Application.CommandBars.Add("vbaPopup", msoBarPopup, , True) 'You can also not do to make the context menu temporary.
         For i = 0 To UBound(a1_file) 'Ubound(a1_ico)
             With .Controls.Add
                  f = p & a1_file(i)
                  If Len(Dir(f)) Then
                     .Picture = LoadPicture(f)
                  Else
                     .FaceId = a1_icon(i) 'If the file is not found, the icon. But it's not necessary.
                  End If
                  .Caption = a2(i)
                  .OnAction = m & a3(i)
             End With
         Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub NoteZoom1(): NoteChangeSize 200, 110: End Sub

Private Sub NoteZoom2(): NoteChangeSize 600, 400: End Sub

Private Sub NoteZoom3()
    With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
         NoteChangeSize .Width, .Height, True
         'With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1) 'Without check
         '     NoteChangeSize .Width, .Height, True
         'End With
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub NoteChangeSize(w!, h!, Optional scr As Boolean)
    With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape
         .Width = w: .Height = h
         If scr Then .Top = 0: .Left = 0: .Visible = msoTrue
    End With
End Sub

 'To create a `Note` with `InputBox`.
Private Sub NoteZoom_InputBox()
'Ниже 2 строчки для проверки наличия `Примечания`.
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim lH As Long 'height
    Dim lW As Long 'width
    lH = Application.InputBox("Choose the HEIGHT of the notes ")
    lW = Application.InputBox("Choose the WIDTH of the notes ")
    With ActiveCell.Comment
'        .Text Text:="Note:" & Chr(10) & ""
        .Shape.Height = lH
        .Shape.Width = lW
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub NoteTextToClipboard()
    With New DataObject
         .SetText ActiveCell.Comment.Text
         .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

For more details you can [download](https://my-files.ru/o1gsps) my Excel Workbook to see how it's implemented!

Also i find code on this site [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win002.htm). I wish to add "Submenu" in my "Menu"! Wrote out only those codes which can help to create "Submenu". *But how to combine I don't know*!?

---

```
Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
'Add PopUp menu
With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
                                 MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

    'Add menu with two buttons
    Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    With MenuItem
        .Caption = "My Special Menu"

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Button 1 in menu"
            .FaceId = 71
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
        End With
```

**In the end I want to get this:**
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

0Key finally i find some solution for this. Right now it's looks like this:
[image: RightClickMenuCursor with <code>SubMenu</code>]

Looks cool right? Download full code [link](https://my-files.ru/wj7ta0).